# DOS debug.exe does not want to enter a string

Tags: command, dos, enter

I'm trying out programming with debug tool found in DOS and Windows - writing simple program dumping Hello World! string to the console. In Windows everything works fine (it however switches my czech keyboard to the US one). In DOS it does not switch the keyboard settings to default US one and uses czech one I use to complete tasks. But when I use enter command, type in the desired string and hit enter, it says Error.

I typed `-e 102 'Hello World!',0D,0A,'$'` in the console, just like in tut, and hit enter - error. Did it multiple times - error. It's exactly like in tutorial, but it does not work. Does debug tool support another keyboard than the US one? It seems it don't, but how to get it working? What if I decide to write czech text containing acutes and carons above letters in the program code as strings to dump? Do I need to install additional binaries to get my keyboard working properly with debug?

Comment: [This](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/76484093/HELLO.JPG) is what the error message is like.

Comment: Can you post the text of the error message in your question?

Comment: @mjsqu It is - It says Error. There is curcumflex, space and Error typed. In the comment there is screenshot what it looks like in DOS (running in VM)

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out :) It was my fault - I had to use double-quotes :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I figured out how to enter message in DOS - I had to use double-quotes instead of single. Strange... Anyway I finally got it working...